# How to add a correction to the parameters in logistic regression s.t. the decision boundary is corrected?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, logarithm, odds

Sometimes we would like to correct the decision boundary of a pretrained logistic regression model $p(y_{temp}=1|x)$, for example by multiplying by a prior in pursuit of adapting better to the distribution of the real data.
Considering a transformation of the form:

$p(y_{real}=1|x) = \frac{p(y_{temp}=1|x)}{\alpha}$

How is this going to modify the decision boundary? I was really hoping that this could be something like modifying the log odds s.t. the new scores become $\theta^Tx + \theta_0 + log(\frac{1}{\alpha})$ but in some other sources I have seen the correction to become rather $\theta^Tx + \theta_0 + log(\frac{2-\alpha}{\alpha})$ which really looks "much better" when looking at the decision boundary plot.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just adjust the cutoff threshold?

Comment: Because the added term could be obtained from any statistical characteristics of the data that we might know in advance, thus motivating the necessity to understand the change in decision boundary by multiplying the output probabilities